# how to run an external .exe file to your application in php

Tags: php

i am new to PHP not know much about PHP and its functions.
i want to convert an doc file to pdf file using an software which is already installed in my machine and i want to use this sotware's .exe file to open in my application an then i will convert the doc files to pdf file. and store in my machine.
my question is how i run the .exe file to the convertor in my application.
i used these three functions:

```
-exec()
-passthru()
-system()

$path = "C:\Program Files\converter.exe";

$result =  exec("$path" $output);

print_r($output);
```

but these will not give a blank page

thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

try change to:

```
exec($path, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: @cherry check manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and then try var_dump($output); What does your converter.exe return ?

Comment: its convert an doc file to pdf. i want to open this executable file of the software in my application. is this possible to open an GUI of a software by using exec function??

Answer (score 0):

Your "path" is a string, not the variable. Try using the following:
`$result = exec($path, $output);`

And does'nt need the converter some arguments about what to convert?

Comment: its not working. can u suggest me another way to run this exe file in my application??